# Delphi FMX - read only checkbox in opendialog?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

In a new blank Delphi Rio FMX app for Windows 32, there is an Opendialog with Options that include ofReadOnly.

The Read Only checkbox does not appear. How do I get it to appear? And how do I check the dialog box in code to see if the user has checked Read Only when opening a file?

Comment: Does the set perhaps include `ofHideReadOnly`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That doesn't help. See this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/660694c8-dc1e-4710-b1c3-234a5ac489a3/ifiledialogsetoptions-fileopendialogoptions-fosreadonly-missing. It seems the customization to suit the existing options has been missed in FMX

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report it.

Comment: Reported as a bug https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19266